# Recover wordpress database with only ibdata1

Tags: mysql, data-recovery

Our server lost all mysql databases in ways I can not explain. Perhaps someone deleted the folders. A team member maybe - investigations are going on.

But right now I need to restore the data.

I only have the structure below inside /var/lib/mysql

[image]

Is it possible to restore the database using these files only?

All my google attempts keep talking about having the .frm files which I do not have anymore.

Please help - I've found about 4 methods but I get stuck since they require .frm files.

The mysql server is dead too, it wont start and I can no longer rely on the server. Logs were cleared too.

Comment: If files were deleted ? why not use a recovery software for UNdeleting the files ?

Comment: We are in the process of attempting this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file listed above won't help you to recover your database. The best way is to change the disk of the server, install a new disk and then run recovery and investigations (there are several forensics tools available for that. The more you use the current disk the more you will lose a chance to recover or gather investigation data).

But this is only possible if you have physical access to the system. Also as a side note, it's a learning experience that production server details should be private and not shared with anyone, there are multiple ways to keep root credentials safe and have setups to update your code or server.

Have a look, may be of your use:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54018

Answer (score 0):

First step must be to create a backup of remaining files to a safe place and only after that proceed to data recovery.

If you know the structure of the lost database you can try to

- reinitialize mysql from scratch to make mysql server running again.
- Then create empty database and tables in it with original names and structure. This will create missing .frm files.
- Stop mysq server, replace newly created files with files from backup. Don't forget to check files' permissions and ownership.
- Start mysql server again. Hopefully it will be able to recover your data.